# Two column layout in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm not sure if this is a general web design or Wordpress question.

I have a simple demo here to illustrate my question.

http://www.ttmt.org.uk/forum/wp/

It's just a simple 2 column responsive layout.

My simple question is how do I spilt the content between the two columns.

The page will be a Page in Wordpress and not posts (I think).

I wanted to create a page in Wordpress and place the text on the content area

There is one content area in Wordpress, is there a way to split this content
so I can say this is the left column, this is the right column.

The text will all be on the same subject but I need to split it between two columns.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for how to make three columns out of the existing two than have a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/). If you are looking for a way to make it possible to enter the content in a way that you are able to output the different columns in different places in the theme, than there are a lot of ways.

In general you need some kind of »container« for each column, so you could start by adding div-containers by using the plain text editor when creating a post or page. You can also use the custom fields to enter more columns. There are also [plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multi-column-tag-map/) available (I never used one for this) and last but not least: you can create your plugin and hook into the page/post-edit page and add additional fields to the input field. With such a plugin you also create a custom post type and hook only into its editing form.

The solutions range from »cheap and fast« to »rather complex« and it depends how comfortable the editing should or has to be. If it is only for you than simple hacks in the editor might satisfy your needs, but if it is for a client who is not that good in html you should consider something »stronger«.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is design issue rather than Wordpress. Wordpress fetch content as a single item and displays it. If you want to display the content in multiple columns then you can use jQuery plugins like http://www.vanderlee.com/martijn/?page_id=229

Answer (score 0):

You could split your content into column using the [column shortcodes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/column-shortcodes/) plugin from wordpress.org