# Wordpress: Creating columns in footer section

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Currently my footer looks like this: 
[image]

I am using the following html:

```
<div class="mainfooter">
    <!-- 1/2 -->
    <div class="column">
        <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar('footer-left-widget') ) ?>
        <h3> Customer Service </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <?php if ( !function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) || !dynamic_sidebar('footer-right-widget') ) ?>
        <h3> Contact Us</h3>
        <div class="fb-like-box" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/LIdylle-Idyll/466829146717006" data-width="30" data-height="60" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="false" data-header="true" data-stream="false" data-show-border="true"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /End 2/2 -->
</div>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
.site-footer .mainfooter .column {               
    position: relative; 
    width: 44%; 
    padding: 3%; 
    float: left;                
}               
.site-footer .mainfooter .column:nth-child(1) { left: 50%; }
.site-footer .mainfooter .column:nth-child(2) { right: 50%; }
.site-footer .mainfooter:before .mainfooter:after{
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;    
}

.site-footer .mainfooter:after{
    left: 50%;
    background: #eee;       
}
```

I went through previous comments and posts on the same like : [Two column layout in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996411/two-column-layout-in-wordpress) and tried all the methods mentioned here : http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/ but I am still not able to solve this.

I added the following code in the functions.php file too:

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer Left',
        'id'   => 'footer-left-widget',
        'description'   => 'Left Footer widget position.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ));

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer Right',
        'id'   => 'footer-right-widget',
        'description'   => 'Right Footer widget position.',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2>',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>'
    ));
```

I am trying to create two columns with content below each column but I can't get the same to work properly.

Comment: today when I was checking out Twenty Fourteen Theme Implementation, i saw that they are using jquery Masonry plugin to create multi column footer.

Comment: I thought this was a simple case for using CSS.. will look into masonry if no solution can be arrived at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the code in your CSS is not necessary. You need to create a rule for the right and the left panel with something like this:

```
.column {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 44%;
    padding: 3%
}

.column-left {
    float: left;
}

.column-right {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

And add a wraper tag to the two column:

```
.row {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Please have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RdzrC/)